# US state-level: Mean and median per capita income for 1950 to today

Tags: data-request, usa, economics, income

I am looking for mean and median per capita income data for each US-American state and for each decadal year from 1950 to 2010. Ideally, I would like to see the data combined in one data set (in total or per year).

I have found quite a few data sets already but most them date only back to the 1970ies or 80ies. Also, I found [this series](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/release?rid=151) of data sets where the income data is listed separately for each state but (for now) I would like to save me the trouble of downloading and merging all of these individually. I assume, there must exist some complete data sets on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

*note* the below data is for US-wide and not individual states.

---

It's the same data source, but you can get the FRED data but as a national sum from Quandl.

Monthly, from 1959. Refreshed automatically:

**https://www.quandl.com/data/FRED/A229RX0**

The direct link to FRED is provided on the Quandl page for validation: http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/A229RX0.csv

With Quandl you get some API or python/r/matlab libraries. For example:

```
quandl.get("FRED/A229RX0")
```

The FRED data on Quandl is here: https://www.quandl.com/data/FRED-Federal-Reserve-Economic-Data

---

I also checked your original link and it's possible to export more than one state at a time (although not ALL at once)

[image]

The click "Add to Graph"

[image]

Then click Download button.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, philshem. I can already foresee, that in the end I might have to download all of the files in my link (thank you for the tip with multiple downloads!) but I thought median income per state should be so obvious that some complete data set must exist somewhere already. Let's see if anyone else knows one.

Comment: If you do collect the individual states, consider repackaging and sharing the data in an easier to access format (it wouldn't have to be automatically updated).